# How to properly map entity to more than one entity type in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm not experienced in Hibernate. Now I'm trying to figure out how to properly map an entity in more than one association. Let me clarify it. Let's say we have Student and Manager entities. These two entities should have an OneToMany association with Address entity.
At first I understand we need to keep a reference of Student or Manager inside of Address entity. Something like the following snippet:

```
class Student{

    @Id
    public long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
    public Set<Address> addresses;
    
         //getters and setters
}
    
class Manager{
      @Id
      public long id;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy="manager")
      public Set<Address> addresses;
    
         //getters and setters
}

class Address{
       @Id
       public long id;

       @ManyToOne
       public Student student

       @ManyToOne
       public Manager manager;

}
```

I'm not sure this is the right approach. It doesn't look right IMHO. If we'll have another entity which needs Address another attribute will be necessary in Address class.
So, how could I properly map the Address entity inside the other entities which will be associated with it?
Thank you

Comment: Hm, don't know if your use case allows to define a base class like "Person" having the OneToMany to adresses and derive Student and Manager from Person and map it as inheritance in Hibernate?

Comment: It works fine for this example of Student and Manager. But now let's say we have Person and Company. Both of them need the Address entity. Or even, Person, Company and PublicOrg. Ok. I know we still can inherit from Organization but my point is: Is it the right approach or there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `@OneToMany` relationship; `@ElementCollection` allows you to implement this mapping. You can have multiple entities (Student, Manager, whatever...) reference the same Embeddable `Address` class.

Take a look at [@ElementCollection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) :

> An ElementCollection mapping can be used to define a collection of
> Embeddable objects. This is not a typical usage of Embeddable objects
> as the objects are not embedded in the source object's table, but
> stored in a separate collection table. This is similar to a OneToMany,
> except the target object is an Embeddable instead of an Entity.

Address class:

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {
   // ...
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student{

    // ...

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Address> addresses;
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

Manager class:

```
class Manager{
    // ...

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Address> addresses;
    
    //getters and setters
}
```